# Grep to look in specific directories under main directory

Tags: linux, grep

Lets say I have the following directory structure:

```
main_dir
 - subdir
   - fabricators
   - other directories
 - subdir
   - fabricators
   - other directories ..
 - subdir
   - fabricators
   - other directories ..
```

Now from the main directory how can one search only in directory `fabricator` excluding other directories?

Answer (score 1):

Use shell wildcards:

```
grep searchstring main_dir/*/fabricators/*
```